# EKEventStore requestAccessToEntityType crashing app in iOS 10 and above

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

I have app in which I have to add events in default calendar which worked fine until iOS 10. Now in iOS 10 it is not granting access. I have set `use legacy swift language version` to `yes`. My code is

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) {
   case .Authorized:
            //access
   case .Denied:
            print("Access denied")
   case .NotDetermined:
       eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion:
                {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if granted {
                        //access
                    } else {
                        print("Access denied")
                    }
                })
   default:
            print("Case Default")
  }
```

While debug my app is crashing at `eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType` in Xcode 8.

[image: Screenshot of debug]

My app is live and I need to solve it. Any help is appropriated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On iOS 10 builds, you need to set a description message for the permission alert on Info.plist

> Important: An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its
>   Info.plist file the usage description keys for the types of data it
>   needs to access or it will crash. To access Reminders and Calendar
>   data specifically, it must include NSRemindersUsageDescription and
>   NSCalendarsUsageDescription, respectively.

from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: It's really weird that it just crashes with no warning or console output. Usually you get an explicit warning about this.

Comment: I agree, there should be some kind of warning, the same thing was happening to the camera permission, took me a while to figure out

Answer (score 1):

```
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {
case .authorized: break
//access
case .denied:
    print("Access denied")
case .notDetermined:
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion:
        {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if granted {
                //access
            } else {
                print("Access denied")
            }
        })
default:
    print("Case Default")
}
```

With XCode 8 and swift 3, this is the new format. Did you test your app on iOS 10.

Comment: Yes, I have test in iOS 10 - Xcode 8. And I haven't migrated to swift 3. For UI issue of storyboard in Xcode 8, I have to use Xcode 7.3.